# Angular $http post call passing data issue to GO backend

Tags: angularjs, http, post, go, call

I am trying to get access to backend written in GO which in 99% is good (problem does not lay there).

For now I just created simplest call which stay in controller (it will be in service in future) to register new user. Although I hardcoded data which I am passing the response says 403 forbidden. In powerShell shows reason of 403:

> RegistrationForm parse - email: , nick:
>
> Validation failed for email - blank

It looks like I am not passing my data correctly because email is blank. Please take a look at my code:

```
$ctrl.fake_registerSubmit = function() {

    $http({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/v1/sign_up',
        headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
         },
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            email: 'check@onet.pl',
            nick: 'borysxoxo',
            password: 'admin12312',
            password_confirmation: 'admin12312'
        }
    })

    .then(function successCall(response, post) {
        console.log('user added');

    }, function errorCall(respone) {
        console.log('error callback');
        console.log(respone);
    })

};
```

This screenshot presents API documentation which I am trying to access:

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy4AD.png)

What am I doing wrong? Is there other way to pass data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending some json data with the wrong `Content-Type`.
I see 2 options, either change `Content-Type` in your header to:

`'Content-type' : 'application/json'`

or transform your payload to:

```
data: "email=check@onet.pl&nick=borysxoxo&password=admin12312&password_confirmation=admin12312"
```

Comment: Thank you Dario it was the problem indeed.